# submiting with ajax and displaying the data on input or div

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this php script to count button clicks to a txt file

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['clicks1'])) {
    incrementClickCount1();
}

function getClickCount1() {
    return (int) file_get_contents("count_files/clickcount1.txt");
}

function incrementClickCount1() {
    $count = getClickCount1() + 1;
    file_put_contents("count_files/clickcount1.txt", $count);
}

if (isset($_POST['clicks2'])) {
    incrementClickCount2();
}

function getClickCount2() {
    return (int) file_get_contents("count_files/clickcount2.txt");
}

function incrementClickCount2() {
    $count2 = getClickCount2() + 1;
    file_put_contents("count_files/clickcount2.txt", $count2);
}
?>
```

---

this is my html

```
<?php
include ('counter.php');
?>
<div class="count_right"><?php echo getClickCount1(); ?></div>
<div class="count_left"><?php echo getClickCount2(); ?></div>
<form action="counter.php" method="post" >
    <button type="submit" class="vote_right"  name="clicks1" ></button>
    <button type="submit" class="vote_left"  name="clicks2"></button>
</form>
```

---

What I'm trying or want to do is to update the counts on the divs but without refreshing the page. 
I've tried using ajax but could not get the click value to show in the divs.
i thought about using text feilds insted, but dont realy know how.
This is a part of my jquery ajax code i used :

```
$('.vote_right, .vote_left').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'counter.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType:'html',   //expect return data as html from server
        data: $('.form1').serialize(),     
    });
});
```

---

I assume i made a bit of a mess, but thats why I'm here :)

**EDIT**

thanks guys, forgot to mention.. the code works but my problame is that its:

1. refreshes the page after submiting
2. not working when i use `onSubmit="return false"`
3. not displaying changes with `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Your counter will break if two people open it at once.

Comment: ...as for what's been said above, use file locking => http://www.php.net/flock

Comment: thanks guys, forgot to mention.. the code works but my problame is that its:<br/>
1. refreshes the page after submiting
2. not working when i use onSubmit="return false"
3. not displaying changes with e.preventDefault();

Comment: thanks Fred, but i have no idea how to use it. dont know much php

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax.
**Html**

```
<?php
include ('counter.php');
?>


   <div class="vote_right"><?php echo getClickCount1(); ?></div>
    <div class="vote_left"><?php echo getClickCount2(); ?></div>
    <form action="counter.php" method="post" >
        <input type="button" class="vote_right"  name="clicks1" >
        <input type="button" class="vote_left"  name="clicks2" >
    </form>
```

**jquery**

```
$('.vote_right, .vote_left').click(function(){
class_count = $(this).attr("class");
count = $("."+class_count).text();
type = class_count == "vote_right" ? "right" : "left";
$.ajax({
url: 'counter.php',
type: 'post',
data: {"type": type,"count" : count},
success: function(data){
 $("."+class_count).text(data);
  }
});
});
```

In your php you will get which button it clicked by `$_REQUEST["type"]`(left or right) and current count of this button by `$_REQUEST["count"]` . Add these lines at the top of your php file.
**php**

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["type"]){
if($_REQUEST["type"] == "right" )
$_POST['clicks1'] = "1";
else
$_POST['clicks2'] = "1"; 
}
```

It should done your work;

Comment: is there a way to make so the page does not refresh?

Comment: yes if you use ajax then if won't need to page refresh. See my edited answer

Comment: you should not use php function in the html div. You should load counter data by using ajax and set it to the div. If you do so then you will no longer need php file include in the html file. for more basic of jquery ajax see: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/ , http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-ajax.htm

Comment: thanks. theres a : syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\maringo\prince\counter.php on line 2. any ideas?

Comment: can you please update your question with your latest php file?

Comment: done. html and jquery on my files are just like you wrote as well

Comment: can you talk to me in skype? id: awladnas

Comment: i tried to call and text but you just seem to vanish. never mind, thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Add `e.preventDefault();` to your click handler:

```
$('.vote_right, .vote_left').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'counter.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType:'html',   //expect return data as html from server
        data: $('.form1').serialize(),     
    });
});
```